# What's the best deal to order the Date in one format and filter (like) in another?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, datetime, datatables

I've some records on DB, stored with a DateOfBirth `DateTime?` field in the format `yyyyMMdd`, which is nice once I need to order them `asc/desc`.

The fact is, on client side, I display the records as `dd/MM/yyyy`, on a DateTables, which consent a free search text box: a user can type 1/10/20, and all records with Date %1/10/20% must be displayed, filtered on server side (ajax/async).

But of course this doesn't work if the format on the returned json (and returned from DB by LINQ) is in the format `yyyyMMdd`. I can change that format, but than the order will not work anymore (order using `dd/MM/yyyy` won't return the correct asc/desc, due to the nature of the format).

What's the correct way to deal with this problem? Not sure I can intercept the input text with regex in case of "date" (its a free search text, one could insert whatever it wants).

Should I keep two different fields with the same value but different formats? One for order and one for filtering?

```
var data = ctx.Patients.AsNoTracking().Select(p => new
{
    ID = p.ID,
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    LastName = p.LastName,
    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth
}).Select(p => new
{
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.LastName + " " + p.FirstName,
    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
    DateOfBirthFormatted = p.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? DbFunctions.Right("00" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Day, 2) + "/" + DbFunctions.Right("00" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Month, 2) + "/" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Year : "-",
});

// grid filters
string searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToLower();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
    data = data.Where(p =>
          p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue) ||
          p.DateOfBirthFormatted.Contains(searchValue)
    );
}

// grid orders
data = data.OrderBy(p => p.DateOfBirth);
```

Not that good though...

Have you experienced somethigs similar in the past and could you give to me some tips?

Comment: Best thing to do is use strongly-typed Date and DateTime values, rather than stringly-typed dates. Convert to real DateTime as early as possible, keep it that way as long as possible, and only convert back to string for final display to the user. This will save you so much hassle, as well as greatly improve performance and reduce bugs.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn but the string "1/10/20" is not a DateTime. At some point I will of course compare with a string, to see if the %like% part is matched. Or do you have other solutions to filter it?

Comment: C# also has DateOnly, but it's still common to just use a DateTime with all zero's (midnight) for the time portion. You WILL have better results either way.

Comment: Don't ever use `LIKE` for determining things like _month_. If you use the right data type, you then have access to magical things like `DATEPART()` that avoid all the horrible mess you're creating for yourself by treating dates as strings.

Comment: @AaronBertrand how DATEPART() can  help on filtering a data with a pattern such as 1/10/20? Or /10/? Or /2022? And so no? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: You parse the pattern in the C# and convert it to the appropriate SQL, or you provide users with a better way to enter their filter criteria.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn is in your opinion possible with some regex intercept that string and "reverse it" accordely?

Comment: "_Should I keep two different fields with the same value but different formats? One for order and one for filtering?_" - You can use DataTables's built-in support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). This allows you to display a date in one format, but also use different date formats for filtering and sorting. see [related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+orthogonal+dates+example+site%253Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: @andrewJames I need to filter server side, not on client. Both sorting and filtering.

Comment: @NetMage: Runtime Version of the EntityFramework.dll is v4.0.30319. Version is 6.1.3. Database provider is a SQL Server on Azure.

Comment: The `datatables` tag appears to be unrelated to the rest of the question, in that case.